# Delay the return value instead of whole method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Is it possible to delay only the return value and not the whole method like:

```
-(CGFloat)getValue
{
    // code implementation
    return floatvalue; // return float value with some delay.
}
```

Comment: Will that make any difference? If so then you can use sleep(10); If UIHang is not a concern.

Comment: yes it will as per my need

Comment: yup just use `sleep(_timeInterval);` to delay the return statement. I am also wondering what is the need to implement such code?

Comment: sleep(_timeInterval); its a stop process of code take timeInterval second then runs your method

Comment: so the calling method will also need to be halted during this delay period .. ? essentially halting the whole call stack .. ?
couldn't you just call a delegate in the background after some delay that will continuou execution or you could also have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html
this may help you achieve what your looking for

Comment: Instead of returning in the same method u can call anther method with the required delay and return in that method..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a block to call back with return value with delay;

```
- (void)ayncGetValue:(void(^)(id value))returnBlock {

  dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10.f * NSEC_PER_SEC); // delay 10 seconds
  dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    returnBlock(@"hello block");
  });
}
// Usage
[obj ayncGetValue:^(id value) {
  // continue  
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is. Keep this function as normal function :

```
-(void)getValue
{
       // code implementation
       [self performSelector:@selector(returnData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

Add this new function which will return data :

```
-(CGFloat)returnData
{
       return floatvalue;
}
```

The only important thing here will be you'll have to declare floatvalue variable as class lever and not function lever.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)getValue
{
// code implementation

  [self performSelector:@selector(getValue:) withObject:value afterDelay:2];
}

-(CGFloat)getValue:(CGFloat *)float1
{
  return float1;
}
```